# Thy used for My

Tags: thou-thee-thy

Can I use the archaic English THY to interpret as MY or is this a major NO NO ?

Example:  upon the reveal of thy heart (meaning my heart)

Comment: "Thy" literally means "your". That would be exactly the opposite of "my".

Comment: What would lead you to believe that it could or should be used in that way?

Comment: The question is whether you will be understood if you use old words in a new meaning.

Comment: Thy and My are complete opposites, and can't be used to mean the same thing.

Comment: Are you using 'thy heart' in the sense of 'one's heart'? Is that where the idea is coming from?

Comment: If you are trying to go for an old-sounding feel, use "mine heart". The old rule of a/an applies to thy/thine and my/mine (think "Mine eyes have seen the glory of the coming of the Lord"). And, traditionally, h's were covered under the same rules as vowel sounds, hence "an history" and "an hotel".

Answer (score 3):

*Thou*, *thee*, *thy*, *thine* are the archaic second person singular, now replaced in all ordinary speech and writing by *you*, *you*, *your* and *yours*.

Not *my*, no.